# How to set up PEAR on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard

Tags: php, macos, pear, osx-leopard

I'm ultimately trying to install PEAR so I can easily install PHPUnit. I want to set up a Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP, PHPUnit development environment so I can test locally. I already have Apach, MySQL and PHP working. Now all I need is PHPUnit, which means I need PEAR to install it.

I have searched all over, and there are a few variations of "the tutorial" on how to install PEAR on Mac OS X 10.5. However, I can't seem to get any of them to work! Has anyone had success with this? I'm not totally confident that I have everything set up as it should be, so if you could include the "default" Mac OS X 10.5 include paths, or a simple explanation of where everything should go, I would appreciate it.

Following [this](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) tutorial I do the following:

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear > go-pear.php
sudo php -q go-pear.php
```

I press enter until I get to a list with 7 include paths:

```
1. Installation prefix ($prefix) : /Users/andrew
2. Temporary files directory     : $prefix/temp
3. Binaries directory            : $prefix/bin
4. PHP code directory ($php_dir) : $prefix/PEAR
5. Documentation base directory  : $php_dir/docs
6. Data base directory           : $php_dir/data
7. Tests base directory          : $php_dir/tests
```

I change the `Installation prefix` to be `/usr/local`, press enter to continue, type `Y` to also install `PEAR_Frontend_Web-beta, PEAR_Frontend_Gtk2, MDB2`. Eventually, everything is installed.

Next...

On the first try, I think `include_path` was commented out of the php.ini file, but since I've already changed this line, and this is not the first time I've tried installing, I get the following message:

```
WARNING!  The include_path defined in the currently used php.ini does not
contain the PEAR PHP directory you just specified:
</usr/local/PEAR>
If the specified directory is also not in the include_path used by
your scripts, you will have problems getting any PEAR packages working.

Would you like to alter php.ini </private/etc/php.ini>? [Y/n] :
```

I type `Y` and let pear automatically update my include path:

```
php.ini </private/etc/php.ini> include_path updated.

Current include path           : .:/usr/share/pear
Configured directory           : /usr/local/PEAR
Currently used php.ini (guess) : /private/etc/php.ini
```

I press enter to continue, and get the following message:

```
The 'pear' command is now at your service at /usr/local/bin/pear

** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use '/usr/local/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/usr/local/bin' to your PATH environment variable.

Run it without parameters to see the available actions, try 'pear list'
to see what packages are installed, or 'pear help' for help.

For more information about PEAR, see:

  http://pear.php.net/faq.php
  http://pear.php.net/manual/

Thanks for using go-pear!

PHP Warning:  rmdir(/usr/local/temp): Not a directory in /Users/andrew/go-pear.php on line 1237

Warning: rmdir(/usr/local/temp): Not a directory in /Users/andrew/go-pear.php on line 1237
```

**Update:** I think I know why these last two warnings came up. Previously, I tried to fix the temp directory problem by creating a symbolic link to /tmp but if I understand correctly, PEAR is trying to create its own temp directory for installation, then it's going to delete it when it's finished. So I should not have created this symbolic link since it's going to try to delete the temp directory when the installation has finished.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are having?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a few things that could be going wrong here, these are only guesses.

First, there's **two** include paths you'll need to worry about.  The first is your PHP include path.  PEAR libraries are (mostly) just PHP code, specially packaged up.  When you install a PEAR module you're downloading all the PHP code needed for that library, and any other PEAR libraries the library you're installing rely on (sorry about that sentence, but I'm not sure there's a better way to say that).  This include path is set in your php.ini files (one file for your command line php, another for yoru web server php; often the same file).

The second include path you'll need to worry about is your UNIX/shell include path.  This is the path that your computer will search for commands in when you enter a command from a terminal.  The 'pear' command is a command line command.

So, we need to make sure that

1. The php.ini file for your website has the PEAR directory in its include path
2. The php.ini file for your command line php application has the PEAR directory in its include path
3. Your shell application (terminal, likely BASH in you're on OS X) has the PEAR directory in its include path

So, for number 1, put a PHP page on your server that include the function call

```
phpinfo();
```

This will list a bunch of information about your server.  Look for the location of php.ini.  Open this file in a text editor, look for the include_path variable, and add the path to your PEAR directory (don't remove the other paths, just add yours).

For number 2, run the following from your command line

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep '.ini'
```

A bunch of lines will print out, look for the one that reads something like "Loaded Configuration File".  Open this file in a text editor, look for the include_path variable, and add the path to your PEAR directory (don't remove the other paths, just add yours).

Finally, and this is what I think your problem is, we need to ensure that the pear command line command is in your shell/bash path.  That's what this error is refering to

```
** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
```

There should be a file in your home directory named '.bash_profile'. It's a hidden file, so it won't showup in the Finder.  Open it with a text editor. If you're having trouble because this is a hidden file, use the command line pico editor.  Ctrl-X will save from pico

```
cd ~
pico .bash_profile
```

This file gets executed by your shell everytime you open a terminal window.  We're going to add /usr/local/bin to your PATH, which means when you attempt to run a command, yoru computer will search for the command in this folder. Add the following line to the bottom of .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This is, more or less, equivilant to the following PHP code

```
$PATH = '/usr/local/bin:'.$PATH
```

You're adding /usr/local/bin as the first colon-delimited place to look for command, and then adding the rest of the existing path to it.  Once you've added that line, close your terminal, re-open it, and then type

```
pear
```

This should give you a list of valid pear commands, but more importantly will let you know pear is in your path.

Good luck!

Comment: What happens when you type '/usr/local/bin/pear'?

Comment: It would be great if you could add your php.ini include_path syntax. I've gotten this sorta working, but am still having some issues with includes breaking.

Comment: Brilliant! All these checks should be documented in the installation instructions from PEAR itself.

Comment: as `pear` is not coming with OSX these days so path to `pear` needs to be added as per `pear's path` in your machine. For ex. if you're running on XAMPP then you might need to run:
`export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  You "HAVE TO" run the go-pear.php at where you want pear installed, so you need to run it under /usr/local if you want pear binary to be installed under /usr/local/bin

:-)

Answer (score 0):

user "bryan kennedy" (above) wanted to know the syntax for the "include_path" change needed in "php.ini"

(I had a similar problem to the OP and I just fixed the issue with the help of this post.)

the change to php.ini will look like...

```
include_path=".:/path_to_pear_dir/PEAR"
```

this is how it looks when you allow "go-pear.php" to make the change....

```
;***** Added by go-pear
include_path=".:/usr/local/bin/PEAR"
;*****
```