# PHP: PEAR Calendar Grid Not Rendering in Browser

Tags: php, calendar, pear

Am trying to create a grid calendar using PEAR and PHP but when I preview the file in my browser I get the following:

```
*Warning: include(Calendar/Month/Weekdays.php) [function.include]:
   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
   in /Users/x/Sites/p/testing pages/Pear_Date.php on line 8
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Calendar/Month/Weekdays.php'
   for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /Users/x/Sites/p/testing pages/Pear_Date.php
   on line 8
Fatal error: Class 'Calendar_Month_Weekdays' not found
    in /Users/x/Sites/p/testing pages/Pear_Date.php on line 10*
```

I thought I'd fixed this before though. The install log for PEAR stated:

```
*Current include path : .:
Configured directory : /Users/x/PEAR
Currently used php.ini (guess) : 
Press Enter to continue: 
The 'pear' command is now at your service at /Users/x/bin/pear
** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use '/Users/x/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/Users/x/bin' to your PATH environment variable.*
```

I found an article which I thought resolved my problem - [How to set up PEAR on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628838/...-x-10-5-leopard)

So I edited the include_path line in my php.ini file so it reads `include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/x/bin/pear"`
I also updated my `.bash_profile` document so it stated `export PATH=/Users/x/bin:$PATH` like the article said

Hope that gives you enough information to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Your include_path is - as PHP tells you - include_path='.:', i.e. only the current path. You need to reload apache config via (in linux as root / with sudo, I do not know about OS X)

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

If this still does not solve the problem, then restart Apache (just to be safe) and then make sure that include_path is not commented (via a semicolon at the beginning of the line), then repeat.

**[EDIT:]**

if the line in php.ini is a comment, then apache will not parse it.

Is your line (correctly):

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/x/bin/pear"
```

or a comment like:

```
;include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/x/bin/pear"
```

If you need to edit php.ini, then you will have to reload the apache config as decribed above.

Comment: I get a command not found message when I try sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload?

Comment: OK i've managed to reload apache2 but I still get the error message stated in my original q - "include_path='.:'"