# php MAMP path problem

Tags: php, pear, mamp

Hi I downloaded some PEAR files and they're in the bin folder of my MAMP directory. Inside the bin folder, they're in a bunch of subfolders (php 5.3/lib/php/pear etc) as you can see below

However, the files that are requiring PEAR are in htdocs, so they're not connecting at all. As I'm a newbie I'm cautious about taking all of those files from the php folder in bin and moving them into htdocs, yet it would also be a complicated file path to include them in every file from htdocs.

Has anyone used Pear. Is it supposed to be set up like this?

[image: bin and htdocs in MAMP folder]

[image: inside bin]

UPDATE -screenshot of Pear folder, and also screenshot of terminal pointing out suggested locations for pear
[image: Pear]

[image: terminal asking me where to put pear]

```
# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#I HAVE ADDED THE PATH HERE
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/


# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH



File Name to Write: .bash_profile    (HIT ENTER)                                           
^G Get Help         ^T To Files         M-M Mac Format      M-P Prepend
^C Cancel           M-D DOS Format      M-A Append          M-B Backup File
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi I downloaded some PEAR files

Did you downloaded them or the came with MAMP? Did you install pear??

what do you mean by

> files that are requiring PEAR are iin htdocs

Regardless, installing pear is similar for every OS.
So, you have to call the file `php go-pear.phar` in your PHP 5.3 folder (that will install pear)

if not, try these (see MacOS installation depending on your OS version)

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

to reinstall your PEAR

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

http://www.bsp.ca/?p=108

and then you call `sudo pear install package_name` you don't need to include anything in your htdocs. Files that need PEAR (or PEAR packages) will be handled by php once PEAR and related package is is installed

```
# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#I HAVE ADDED THE PATH HERE
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/


# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: thanks,  I have no idea if they came with MAMP. It doesn't say anything about it in my installation. Anyways, someone told me to do this "curl pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar" to download the file, than again "sudo php go-pear.phar"   I did the first but when I did the second i got some ????? and then it exited. This problem is described at this blog http://technosophos.com/content/php-phar-command-line-errors-os-x-running-php-somephar-generates but I couldn't get its solution.

Comment: @Michael do this `$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` This will reinstall the PEAR. the reason you had ?? is beacuse of Unicode characters. I'll update the answer

Comment: and regarding your instructions in your original answer, I don't know how to get to the php 5.3 folder from my command line to call the file php go-pear phar

Comment: I followed your instructions re wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and it said "wget command not found"

Comment: @Micheal where is you MAMP folder located? I don't have Mac near me,  but right-click on folder and see the properties (view info??). this will show the path of the folder. Then in command line type in `cd /path/to/the/folder/`

Comment: do you know why it would say "wget command not found"? thanks

Comment: @Michael  ok,  try with curl `curl pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar`

Comment: @Micahel can you provide a screen shot of your PEAR folder (update your question). You should have .phar there.

Comment: regarding location of MAMP, it is in the Applications folder on the harddrive. The problem is that the default/home directory in my command line has a different Applications folder (i.e. with no MAMP in it) so if I type in cd Applications/MAMP it says the directory doesn't exist. I don't know how to get to the Applications folder with the MAMP in it.

Comment: o.k., we're making progress.  working with your updated instructions (i.e. curl pear.php etc), it accepted the command, and then I entered the next sudo line. Now it's suggesting layout, but I don't know what to select.  I'll post screen shots.  Please note that the root folder for local host is in htdocs inside MAMP, if that will help you decide where the pear should be.

Comment: @Micheal as said, look in the folder properties (right click -> view info) and copy the whole path (it starts with / I forgot the exact folder structure in MAcOs. But yes, your Application folder (command line defaults to your home directory)  is different from system wide Application folder. do the `cd /` that will give you the root folder.

Comment: I clicked on getInfo and it said /Applications.   However, please note that your curl instructions worked, so now my command line is asking me where to install PEAR, so I don't know if I should move away from that screen.  I have posted a screenshot.

Comment: @micheal just hit enter on everything. Once its installed. type in `pear` that will display a list of commands for pear. If it says command not found, that it didn't install properly. Once you do that, install package needed fro your application (in other words: why you had to install PEAR in first place. what package was needed?)

Comment: thinking that 'all' was the same as enter on everything, and it told me the installation base (/Users/michaelmitchell/pear). When I typed "pear" it just gave me a temporary directory for processing and downloads.. One problem. I don't think this is the same Pear that's in MAMP folder, so I don't know if the files in htdocs of MAMP will be able to benefit from this installation that's not in MAMP?

Comment: further to my last comment:  WARNING!  The include_path defined in the currently used php.ini does not
contain the PEAR PHP directory you just specified:
</Users/michaelmitchell/pear/share/pear>

Comment: @micheal, that dosen't matter. All you have to point to correct path by altering php.ini. See `http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini` (MacOS is build on Unix like OS so refer to those options whenever you deal with setig and installations)

Comment: O.K, thanks so much. Is altering the php.ini the same as adding it to the PATh environment variable as it says here: ** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use '/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin' to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Micheal yes. So your path in .ini file will be set to '/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear'. Is pear working when you type in `pear` in command line?

Comment: when I type in pear at the command line, it says "command not found"

Comment: @Micheal Did you install pear?? (proceed with instalation isntruction by pressing Enter?) If yes, then you need to update your envariomental paths. See this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628838/how-to-set-up-pear-on-mac-os-x-10-5-leopard`   `There should be a file in your home directory named '.bash_profile'. It's a hidden file, so it won't showup in the Finder. Open it with a text editor. If you're having trouble because this is a hidden file, use the command line pico editor. Ctrl-X will save from pico`

Comment: Yes, I hit enter.  It says the The 'pear' command is now at your service at /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear  so I changed to that directory and it lists a bunch of available commands (such as list-all) but when I type any of them it says command not avialable.

Comment: If you are in taht folder, then you need to type like this `./pear ` - `./` means  current folder (Unix/Linux/macOs command line is different then on windows/dos )

Comment: the stackoverflow you referred me to said to add the path to my include_path. Currently, my ini file says include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php"  so do I have to put a comma after that before adding the new path? and do I put quotes around it?

Comment: Strange, it says pear is avilable at /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear, but I can only navigate to the bin directory. When I'm in bin and do ls -a, it shows that pear is there, but I can't cd into it

Comment: @Micheal did you look at teh anwer or the question? Look at teh answer. you include path shoudl be path to pear `include_path = "/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin"` What I was refering to is this part `cd ~` then `pico .bash_profile` then  line `export PATH=/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/:$PATH` tpo include bin path to the system. In other words you ahve to set up path in php.ini and the system (computer)

Comment: @Micheal Ok. do this as well. run this command copy/paste in command line  `/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear` is it working?

Comment: @Micheal pear is not a folder its a command (executable) as mentioned unix is differtn then windows. What we are trying to do here is to make `/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/` path available to computer so that we can execute a command `pear` without the need to go into bin folder and execute

Comment: I'm trying to add that line now, but it doesn't have a way to save it. i.e. I have typed the export PATH=/  etc etc but how do I save?

Comment: @micheal what did you use `pico`? `Ctrl-X will save from pico` .

Comment: o.k, I did Ctrl-X, then clicked Y, now it says "File Name to write .bash profile"  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do anything or just exit

Comment: ok. while in pico press `Ctrl-X` (or on mac maybe applekey+X) that will save & exit.

Comment: I closed and re-opened the terminal as that tutorial said, but it's still saying "command not found" when I type pear. So I went and opened .pico again, but the line I had added isn't there. Maybe it didn't save properly.

Comment: can you paste the content fo your .bash_profile file? Also, try this `/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear` (type in command line)  is this working?

Comment: ok @Michael. fist typpe `cd ~` that will take you to your home directory. then type in `pico .bash_profile` and write down those lines. Then press `CTR+X` respond with `Y` when asked that it will be wirtten (are there any errors i.e. permission denied?)

Comment: will check that last command next. I tried to open terminal again and add it. See OP which I will amend.

Comment: After I respond with Y, it says File Name to Write: .bash_profile                                               
^G Get Help         ^T To Files         M-M Mac Format      M-P Prepend
^C Cancel           M-D DOS Format      M-A Append          M-B Backup File

Comment: When I type /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear, it gives me a list of commands, but when I type the commands they say not found.

Comment: o.k., i hit enter and it's saved, but when I type pear in command line, it's command not found.

Comment: i;ve updated my answer copy paste the content into your .bash_profile

Comment: @Micheal , can you please type thsi `/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear` and tell me if its working

Comment: Yes, as mentioned a few comments back, i typed /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear and it prints a list of commands (but when I enter those commands it says command not found)

Comment: @micheal. ok then. copy paste bas_profile code posted/updated in my answer.

Comment: Hey, it's working now when I type "Pear" and also when I type the commands at /Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/pear

Comment: @Micheal finnaly :), ok you have instaled PEAR. double check you php.ini if it has a PEAR path, it shoudl look somethign liek this `include_path=".:/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/"` adn if tahst ok. you have installed PEAR. Now you can istall packages by typing `pear install name_of_the_package`. and use them  in your applications

Comment: But at the same time, it's not available on my webserver. The pear.net. page you referred me to gave me instructions to create a check_php.php page to test it with the following code and it didn't work, so it must not be included properly in my path somewhere <?php
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>

Comment: my php.ini include_path file looks like this (note, i added the pear bin path, the other path was already tehre) include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php" ".:/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/bin/"

Comment: @micheal. Ok run this again `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` and when it list teh folders press 5. Update your PHP code directory  php_idr to the path of PEAR on MAMP

Comment: thanks a lot. it says /Users/michaelmitchell/pear' should I put the ".:" in front of it?

Comment: I tried it with and without the .: and both times it gave a failed to include warning.  The pear.php.net says that the include path must not be correct if I get this warning. 
Warning: require_once(System.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/check_php.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/Users/michaelmitchell/pear') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/check_php.php on line 2

Comment: would I also change hte configuration file that's got a path like this  /Users/michaelmitchell/.pearrc

Comment: and there's also paths like this /tmp/pear/install
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install  do those get changed to Applications/MAMP/ etc?

Comment: @Micheal regarding my previous commeemt. don't forget then to update your .bash_profile with new path and delete pear folder form `/Users/michaelmitchell/` just to make sure. that's it from me now man I have to go. Good luck. If you fail again. try again, read the tutes and start from scracht (reinstall MAMP, pear, everythig) .  dont worry if it looks hard. Once you get it, and undesrtand what is what and why is something needed you'll realise hwo easy it was. its best way to learn as well.

Comment: @micheal. yes man. just point everythign taht was in `/Users/michaelmitchell/` to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR/`