# GRPC Installation - Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so'

Tags: php, grpc

After getting my problem solved [on this brilliant ansewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629136/13815916) on how to get Pear running with success on Mac OS, I'm in trouble with the below errors while I'm trying to install and configure **GRPC** according to [this google instruction](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#using-pecl)

I understand that the problem is that the system is "Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so'"

Please can anybody give me a path on how to solve those issues or maybe show me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running my localhost with **PHP 8** served by MAMP

Thank you very much!!

```
composer require "grpc/grpc:^1.38"
```

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/grpc.so.so)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: After you installed grpc with `pecl install grpc` the installer should have given you the location of the .so library. Did it? If you didn't pay attention to the messages, try to remove and reinstall and check the final output of the pecl installer. It should give you info on if and where it installed the .so

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreaOlivato

I didn't pay attention to it. I'm going to try again and update you about the results.

Comment: The instalation of `sudo pecl install grpc` finish with error as follow:

`/private/tmp/pear/install/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc/byte_buffer.c:19:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/php/ext/grpc/byte_buffer.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed`

Comment: @AndreaOlivato this is the output after the failure. By the way I moved on to PHP7.4 installed with BREW

`Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/share/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/pecl/20190902`

Comment: I **SOLVED** my problem. 

This is my final output after run `sudo pecl install grpc`
`Build process completed successfully
Installing '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/grpc.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/grpc-1.38.0`

How can I write a kind of post here on @StackOverflow for the future, in order to help others?

Comment: Simply answer your own question, then accept it as the solution. I am curious to read it

Comment: Thank you @AndreaOlivato! The "secret" is: 1st is to understand where Homebrew installs all the packages, (by default is `/usr/local/Cellar`), 2nd we need to know how to handle (edit and set new environment variables) `$PATH` variable on MAC OS. 3rd please, always read the error messages or warnings after any failed packaged installation using Homebrew (thanks to @AndreaOlivato with the question). Usually, the error or warning messages tells you exactly what is wrong and should be fixed, in order to be able to succeed with the installation. I'll try to use the next 585 chars for more details.

Comment: Set this variable enviremont:
`export PHPRC="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/conf"directory 
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/bin:$PATH # php executable
#For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
#For pkg-config to find zlib you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"

export PHP_AUTOCONF="/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/bin"
export PHP_AUTOHEADER="/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/bin/autoheader"`

Comment: Follow the google instructions as described in my question.
For Homebrew, on terminal execute this `brew install autoconf`
If, for some reason, you got the `Errno: Permission denied` in a folder or file, you shall run `sudo chmod 777` on it.
For Environment Variables, basically, you must be able to edit and add new entries.

Comment: Note: the 'sudo pecl install grpc' can take a lot of time to process!! Let it running!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is just create directory by run command
"mkdir /usr/local/lib/php/pecl"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using PHP 7.4 in MacOS. When I ran the

```
pecl install grpc
```

... command; it installed the .../20190902/grpc.so inside the current PHP version folder, so, I just copy-paste the grpc.so in the right path mentioned in console:

```
php@7.4/7.426_1/pecl/20190902/grpc.so --> /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so
```

I hope this can be helpful to anybody!