# Xampp - Incorrect PEAR data_dir setting

Tags: php, xampp, pear, phing

I installed Xampp in my Windows 7 machine. The path is C:\xampp. On trying to build a project using phing, I am getting the error

```
The PEAR data_dir setting is incorrect: C:\php\pear\data.
Please edit using 'pear config-set data_dir ...' and re-install Phing.
```

How can I reinstall Phing in Xampp? Can I fix this error by changing some config parameters?

Comment: Can you gothrough it, it will be helpful for you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by resetting phing parameters using the commands

```
pear config-set doc_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\docs
pear config-set cfg_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\cfg
pear config-set data_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\data
pear config-set cache_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\cache
pear config-set download_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\download
pear config-set temp_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\temp
pear config-set test_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\tests
pear config-set www_dir C:\xampp\php\pear\www
```

Then reinstalled phing by

```
pear install phing/phing
```

Now build is working fine.

Comment: That was hard to figure out from the *Please edit using 'pear config-set data_dir ...' and re-install Phing.* error message ;-P - Thanks for reporting back.