# Current directory (./) is not within PHP include path XAMMP

Tags: php, path, directory, include, typo3

Hey i am trying to get TYPO3 CMS 7.6.19 installed but im allways recieving this error...

```
include_path = C:\xampp\htdocs\mrs\vendor/pear/pear_exception C:\xampp\htdocs\mrs\vendor/pear/http_request2 C:\xampp\php\pear
Normally the current path '.' is included in the include_path of PHP. Although TYPO3 does not rely on this, it is an unusual setting that may introduce problems for some extensions.
```

Comment: You have to fix your include_path. I think this is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting PEAR to work on XAMPP (Apache/MySQL stack on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows)

Comment: Nope i tried all of the Answers there no one worked...

Comment: Doesn't the include path need separators? I think it's a colon for Unix and a semicolon for Windows. Also, it seems that the current directory is not included...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to fix your `include_path` in php.ini.

In that file you will find a line that says something similar to:

`include_path = C:\xampp7\php\PEAR`.

To fix change the line below

from
`include_path=C:\xampp7\php\PEAR`
to
`include_path=".;C:\xampp7\php\PEAR"`