# xampp does not run fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I got the following warning and error working on laravel project using xampp:

> **Warning: Unknown:** failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> Unknown on line 0
>
> **Fatal error: Unknown:** Failed opening required 'server.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: can you share your vhosts.conf file here(if you set local path for project) . where you set your project path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved 
My antivirus deleted some of my files. I just turned off and now is working.

Answer (score -1):

just run in cmd or terminal depends on your os
**cd c:/xammp/htdocs/your_laravel_project**

**php artisan serve**

Make sure you installed composer

Comment: it will give:
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
But when trying to open on browser it gives same error

Comment: try typing composer install or composer update in cmd