# How can I set up smart admin in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use smart admin in my laravel and I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine::main(): Failed opening required '../lib/config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

And this is my file

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Gate-To-Iran\resources\views\Admin\inc\init.php:5:

<?php 

//if (session_id() == '')

//    session_start();

require_once("../lib/config.php");

?>
```

I need help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/biPiP.png

Comment: can u put library url and should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows

Comment: I changed it but it did not work . I think its from my config.php