# How can I solve the localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

if i browse
**localhost/visiondms**
it shows,
`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\visiondms/wp-admin.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\visiondms\index.php on line 10`

Please tell my what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

you needs to fix your `include_path` system variable to point to the correct location.

How to do this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows?answertab=active#tab-top)